# Read Protocol Buffers file using Python

Tags: python, homebrew, protocol-buffers

My goal is to parse Protocol Buffers file with an extension *filename*.pb.string. Downloaded Protobuff using Homebrew on Mac. Ran protoc --version and have libprotoc 3.1.0 version.

But when I run Python it says cannot find a module. I changed my .pb file name to _pb2.py and import the module in my Python Script.

```
import filename_pb2 as proto
```

I am using Google Docs but still not having any luck. I am also having issues with compiling Protobuf .so files via Python. I am just not able to process how Protobuf and Python link together. Can someone please guide me?

**Python Error**

```
import response_123_pb2 as proto
ImportError: No module named response_123_pb2
```

Comment: "cannot find a module"?  Please post the full error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compile your .proto file to a *_pb2.py file:

> protoc --python_out=./ YourProto.proto

Make sure it produces a file named YourProto_pb2.py. Then you can import it to your code with:

```
import YourProto_pb2 as proto
```

If you are having other problems with the compile, then it is another matter. Be sure to check out this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial).